# Getting input into Netwire programs

Tags: haskell, frp, netwire

I'm getting started with Netwire version 5.

I have no problem writing all the wires I want to transform my inputs into my outputs.

Now the time has come to write the IO wrapper to tie in my real-world inputs, and I am a bit confused.

Am I supposed to create a custom session type for the `s` parameter of `Wire s e m a b` and embed my sensor values in there?

If so, I have these questions:

1. What's up with the `Monoid s` context of `class (Monoid s, Real t) => HasTime t s | s -> t`? What is it used for?
2. I was thinking of tacking on a `Map String Double` with my sensor readings, but how should my monoid crunch the dictionaries? Should it be left-biased? Right-biased? None of the above?

If not, what am I supposed to do? I want to end up with wires of the form `Wire s InhibitionReason Identity () Double` for some `s`, representing my input.

It's my understanding that I don't want or need to use the monadic `m` parameter of `Wire` for this purpose, allowing the wires themselves to be pure and confining the IO to the code that steps through the top-level wire(s). Is this incorrect?

Comment: There's a monoid instance for Map that's left biased. And I'd actually think making the monadic context here a reader monad and stuffing your sensor information in there would be reasonable here. This doesn't really impact the place where you step your wires because you can just `runReader` (or `runReaderT` if you wanna stuff in even more stuff).

Comment: Tutorials/examples out there suggest to use IO actions in inner wires to get sensor data. e.g. use `mkGen_` with `getKey` in it. I would be interested in generalizing the question to: "What are advantages and disadvantages of allowing IO actions inside wires, as compared to feeding all IO data as input to the outermost wire?"

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to put data into a `Wire s e m a b` is via the input `a`. It's possible, through the use of `WPure` or `WGen` to get data out of the state delta `s` or the underlying `Monad` `m`, but these take us further away from the main abstractions. The main abstractions are `Arrow` and `Category`, which only know about `a b`, and not about `s e m`.

Here's an example of a very simple program, providing input as the input `a`. `double` is the outermost wire of the program. `repl` is a small read-eval-print loop that calls `stepWire` to run the wire.

```
import FRP.Netwire
import Control.Wire.Core

import Prelude hiding (id, (.))

double :: Arrow a => a [x] [x]
double = arr (\xs -> xs ++ xs)

repl :: Wire (Timed Int ()) e IO String String -> IO ()
repl w = do
    a <- getLine
    (eb, w') <- stepWire w (Timed 1 ()) (Right a)
    putStrLn . either (const "Inhibited") id $ eb
    repl w'

main = repl double
```

Notice that we pass in the time difference to `stepWire`, not the total elapsed time. We can check that this is the correct thing to do by running a different top-level wire.

```
timeString :: (HasTime t s, Show t, Monad m) => Wire s e m a String
timeString = arr show . time

main = repl timeString
```

Which has the desired output:

```
a
1
b
2
c
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this in an Arrow way, so this might be more composible. You can read my posts if you like. [Kleisli Arrow in Netwire 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745934/kleisli-arrow-in-netwire-5) and [Console interactivity in Netwire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992299/console-interactivity-in-netwire/32836079). The second post has a complete interactive program

First, you need this to lift Kleisli functions (That is, anything `a -> m b`):

```
mkKleisli :: (Monad m, Monoid e) => (a -> m b) -> Wire s e m a b
mkKleisli f = mkGen_ $ \a -> liftM Right $ f a
```

Then, assuming you want to get characters from terminal, you can lift `hGetChar` by doing this:

```
inputWire :: Wire s () IO () Char
inputWire = mkKleisli $ \_ -> hGetChar stdin
```

I haven't tested this `runWire` function (I just stripped code off from my previous posts), but it should run your wires:

```
runWire :: (Monad m) => Session m s -> Wire s e m () () -> m ()
runWire s w = do
  (ds, s') <- stepSession s
  -- | You don't really care about the () returned
  (_, w') <- stepWire w ds (Right ())
  runWire s' w'
```

You can compose the input wire wherever you like like any other Wires or Arrows. In my example, I did this (don't just copy, other parts of the program are different):

```
mainWire = proc _ -> do 
  c <- inputWire -< ()
  q <- quitWire -< c
  outputWire -< c
  returnA -< q
```

Or, one-liner:

```
mainWire = inputWire >>> (quitWire &&& outputWire) >>> arr (\(q,_) -> q)
```