# Console interactivity in Netwire?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, frp, netwire

I am testing with the `Netwire` haskell library and made it work with a simple `time` wire:

```
import Control.Wire
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Functor.Identity
import System.IO

wire :: (HasTime t s) => Wire s () m a t
wire = time

run :: (HasTime t s, MonadIO m, Show b, Show e) =>
       Session m s -> Wire s e m a b -> m ()
run session wire = do
  (dt, session') <- stepSession session
  (wt', wire') <- stepWire wire dt $ Right undefined
  case wt' of
    -- | Exit
    Left _ -> return ()
    Right x -> do
      liftIO $ do
        putChar '\r'
        putStr $ either (\ex -> show ex) show wt'
        hFlush stdout
        -- Interactivity here?
        gotInput <- hReady stdin
        if gotInput then
          return ()
          else return ()
      run session' wire'

main :: IO ()
-- main = testWire clockSession_ wire
main = run clockSession_ wire
```

Note: the `run` is basically modified from `testWire`, so I don't know if it is the correct way to form a network of wires. Part of the code origin from http://todayincode.tumblr.com/post/96914679355/almost-a-netwire-5-tutorial but that tutorial does not say about events.

Now I am trying to add a bit interactivity to the program. For now, quit the program when any key is pressed. I suppose I should do some event switching. However, I am stuck here because I cannot find a way to either change `wire'` or switch the behaviour. I tried to read the API document and the source, but I don't see how to actually "fire" an Event or using it to switch the wire.

Again, since I am not yet very familiar with Haskell, I may have made some big stupid mistakes here.

**Update 1/2**

I got my goal working by the following code. The timer stops on any key press. *Update 2* I managed to separate out `pollInput` into another `IO` only function, Yay!

```
import Control.Wire
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Functor.Identity
import System.IO

wire :: (HasTime t s) => Wire s () m a t
wire = time

run :: (HasTime t s, MonadIO m, Show b, Show e) =>
       Session m s -> Wire s e m a b -> m ()
run session wire = do
  -- Get input here
  input <- liftIO $ pollInput

  (dt, session') <- stepSession session
  (wt', wire') <- stepWire wire dt $ input
  case wt' of
    -- | Exit
    Left _ -> liftIO (putStrLn "") >> return ()
    Right x -> do
      liftIO $ do
        putChar '\r'
        putStr $ either (\ex -> show ex) show wt'
        hFlush stdout

      run session' wire'

pollInput :: IO (Either a b)
pollInput =  do
  gotInput <- hReady stdin
  if gotInput then
    return (Left undefined)
    else return (Right undefined)


setup :: IO ()
setup = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering


main :: IO ()
main = do
  setup
  run clockSession_ wire
```

However, this raises some further questions. First, is this good practise? <del>Second, what is the type of `pollInput`? I tried to manually type it out but without success. Automatic type deduction works, though.</del>

This is my explanation of how this code works:

First, the user input from console is polled, and after some logic, the "input" to wire is generated (poor name choice, but that input generated is the wire input) and passed along the network. Here, I simply pass an inhibition (`Left something`), and will cause the loop to exit. Of course, when exiting, the program produces a newline to make console look nicer.

(Well, I still don't understand how `Event` works, though)

**Update 3/4**

After reading @Cirdec 's answer, and fiddled a lot on my editor, I get this single threaded version without `IORef`, also quitting on pressing 'x'*Update 4*: <del>(but  it does not output anything)</del>:

```
import Control.Wire
import Prelude hiding ((.),id)
import Control.Wire.Unsafe.Event
import System.IO
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

data InputEvent = KeyPressed Char 
                | NoKeyPressed
                deriving (Ord, Eq, Read, Show)
type OutputEvent = IO ()

--- Wires
example :: (HasTime t s, Monad m, Show t) =>
           Wire s () m (Event [InputEvent]) (Event [OutputEvent])
example = switch $
          (fmap ((:[]) . print) <$> periodic 1 . time
           &&&
           fmap (const mkEmpty) <$> filterE (any (== KeyPressed 'x'))
           )

readKeyboard :: IO (Either e (InputEvent))
readKeyboard = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  gotInput <- hReady stdin
  if gotInput then do
    c <- getChar
    return $ Right $ KeyPressed c
    else return $ Right $ NoKeyPressed

output :: [OutputEvent] -> IO ()
output (x:xs) = id x >> output xs
output _ = return ()

run :: (HasTime t s, MonadIO m) =>
       Session m s -> Wire s e m (Event [InputEvent]) (Event [OutputEvent]) -> m e
run = go
  where
    go session wire = do
      -- | inputEvent :: Event InputEvent
      inputEvent <- liftIO $ readKeyboard
      (dt, session') <- stepSession session
      (wt', wire') <- stepWire wire dt (Event <$> (fmap (:[]) inputEvent))
      -- (wt', wire') <- stepWire wire dt (Right undefined)
      case wt' of
        Left a -> return a
        Right bEvent -> do
          case bEvent of
            Event b -> liftIO $ output b
            _ -> return ()
          go session' wire'

main = do
  run clockSession_ example
```

I think this is much better than my original, but I am still not completely convinced whether it is good practise or not.

Comment: The easiest way to get input in and output out of netwire is [through the inputs and outputs of the outermost wire](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636139/414413).

Comment: The thing is, I am trying to prevent the input from blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would point to [Kleisli Arrow in Netwire 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745934/kleisli-arrow-in-netwire-5). I came up with that answer after a longggg time of trying to understand Monads and Arrows. <del>I will put a minimal example using Kleisli Wire soon.</del>

This program merely echos what the user types, and quits when it hits a `q`. Though useless, it demonstrates a probably good practice of using Netwire 5.

```
mkKleisli :: (Monad m, Monoid e) => (a -> m b) -> Wire s e m a b
mkKleisli f = mkGen_ $ \a -> liftM Right $ f a
```

This is the Kleisli wire constructor written in the answer in the post referenced. In summary, this function lifts any Kleisli function `a -> m b` into `Wire s e m a b`. This is the core about any I/O we are doing in this program.

Since we are echoing as user types, `hGetChar` is probably the best choice. Therefore, we lift that into a wire.

```
inputWire :: Wire s () IO () Char
inputWire = mkKleisli $ \_ -> hGetChar stdin
```

Similarly, we use the following wire to output characters on screen.

```
outputWire :: Wire s () IO Char ()
outputWire = mkKleisli $ putChar
```

Then to determine when we need to quit, a pure wire is constructed to output `True` when `q` is the input (Note that `mkSF_` can be used instead of `arr`).

```
quitWire :: (Monad m, Monoid e) => Wire s e m Char Bool
quitWire = arr $ quitNow
    where 
      quitNow c 
          | c == 'q' || c == 'Q' = True
          | otherwise = False
```

To actually use the information of quitting, we need to write a special (but really simple) `runWire` function which runs a wire of type `Wire s e m () Bool`. When the wire is inhibited or returns false, the function ends.

```
runWire :: (Monad m) => Session m s -> Wire s e m () Bool -> m ()
runWire s w = do
  (ds, s') <- stepSession s
  (quitNow, w') <- stepWire w ds (Right ())
  case quitNow of
    Right False -> runWire s' w'
    _ -> return ()
```

Now, let's put wires together.

```
mainWire = inputWire >>> (quitWire &&& outputWire) >>> arr (\(q,_) -> q)
```

Of course we can use the Arrow syntax:

```
mainWire = proc _ -> do 
  c <- inputWire -< ()
  q <- quitWire -< c
  outputWire -< c
  returnA -< q
```

Not sure if the `proc` version is faster or not, but in this simple example, both are quite readable.

We get input from `inputWire`, feed it to both `quitWire` and `outputWire` and get a tuple `(Bool, ())`. Then we take the first one as the final output.

At last, we run everything in `main`!

```
main = do 
  hSetEcho stdin False 
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering 
  runWire clockSession_ mainWire
```

Here comes the final code I used:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

module Main where

import Control.Wire
import Control.Monad
import Control.Arrow
import System.IO
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

mkKleisli :: (Monad m, Monoid e) => (a -> m b) -> Wire s e m a b
mkKleisli f = mkGen_ $ \a -> liftM Right $ f a

inputWire :: Wire s () IO () Char
inputWire = mkKleisli $ \_ -> hGetChar stdin

outputWire :: Wire s () IO Char ()
outputWire = mkKleisli $ putChar

quitWire :: (Monad m, Monoid e) => Wire s e m Char Bool
quitWire = arr $ quitNow
    where 
      quitNow c 
          | c == 'q' || c == 'Q' = True
          | otherwise = False

runWire :: (Monad m) => Session m s -> Wire s e m () Bool -> m ()
runWire s w = do
  (ds, s') <- stepSession s
  (quitNow, w') <- stepWire w ds (Right ())
  case quitNow of
    Right False -> runWire s' w'
    _ -> return ()

mainWire = inputWire >>> (quitWire &&& outputWire) >>> arr (\(q,_) -> q)

main = do 
  hSetEcho stdin False 
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering 
  runWire clockSession_ mainWire
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to block on input and output, don't block on input and output. To demonstrate how to hook up netwire to events, we'll make a little framework for running wires. We'll avoid blocking the stepping of the wire by performing all `IO` in separate threads.

From the [netwire documentation](http://hub.darcs.net/ertes/netwire), we are allowed to deconstruct `Event`s if we are developing a framework.

> Netwire does not export the constructors of the `Event` type by default. If you are a framework developer you can import the `Control.Wire.Unsafe.Event` module to implement your own events.

This lets us see that [`Event`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-5.0.1/docs/Control-Wire-Unsafe-Event.html#t:Event) is just

```
data Event a = NoEvent | Event a
```

We will make a very simple framework that uses one action in `m` for input and one for output. It runs an action `m (Either e a)` to read an action or inhibit. It either runs an action `b -> m ()` to output or stops when the wire inhibits.

```
import Control.Wire
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)

import Control.Wire.Unsafe.Event

run :: (HasTime t s, Monad m) =>
       m (Either e a) -> (b -> m ()) ->
       Session m s -> Wire s e m (Event a) (Event b) -> m e
run read write = go
    where
        go session wire = do
            (dt, session') <- stepSession session
            a <- read
            (wt', wire') <- stepWire wire dt (Event <$> a)
            case wt' of
                Left e -> return e
                Right bEvent -> do
                    case bEvent of
                        Event b -> write b
                        _       -> return ()
                    go session' wire'
```

We will use this to run an example program that outputs the time every second and stops (inhibits) when the `'x'` key is pressed.

```
example :: (HasTime t s, Monad m, Show t) =>
           Wire s () m (Event [InputEvent]) (Event [OutputEvent])
example = switch $
            (fmap ((:[]) . print) <$> periodic 1 . time)
            &&&
            (fmap (const mkEmpty) <$> filterE (any (== KeyPressed 'x')))
```

The input and output events carry multiple events in case more than one event takes place in the same time step. The input events are just pressed character keys. The output events are `IO` actions.

```
data InputEvent = KeyPressed Char 
  deriving (Ord, Eq, Read, Show)
type OutputEvent = IO ()
```

Our non-blocking IO will run three threads: an input thread, an output thread, and a wire thread. They will communicate with each other by atomically modifying `IORef`s. This is overkill for an example program (we could have just used `hReady` when reading) and not enough for a production program (The IO threads will spin waiting on characters and output). In practice polling for events and scheduling output will usually be provided by some other IO framework (OpenGL, a gui toolkit, a game engine, etc).

```
import Data.IORef

type IOQueue a = IORef [a]

newIOQueue :: IO (IOQueue a)
newIOQueue = newIORef []

readIOQueue :: IOQueue a -> IO [a]
readIOQueue = flip atomicModifyIORef (\xs -> ([], reverse xs))

appendIOQueue :: IOQueue a -> [a] -> IO ()
appendIOQueue que new = atomicModifyIORef que (\xs -> (reverse new ++ xs, ()))
```

The main thread sets up the queues, spawns the IO threads, runs the wire, and signals the IO threads when the program has stopped.

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Concurrent.Async

import Control.Monad.IO.Class

runKeyboard :: (HasTime t s, MonadIO m) =>
               Session m s -> Wire s e m (Event [InputEvent]) (Event [OutputEvent]) -> m e
runKeyboard session wire = do
    stopped <- liftIO newEmptyMVar 
    let continue = isEmptyMVar stopped
    inputEvents  <- liftIO newIOQueue
    outputEvents <- liftIO newIOQueue
    inputThread  <- liftIO $ async (readKeyboard continue (appendIOQueue inputEvents .    (:[])))
    outputThread <- liftIO $ async (runEvents    continue (sequence_ <$> readIOQueue outputEvents))
    let read  = liftIO $ Right <$> readIOQueue   inputEvents 
    let write = liftIO .           appendIOQueue outputEvents
    e <- run read write session wire
    liftIO $ putMVar stopped ()
    liftIO $ wait inputThread
    liftIO $ wait outputThread
    return e
```

The input thread waits for keys, spinning when there is no input ready. It sends `KeyPressed` events to the queue.

```
import System.IO

readKeyboard :: IO Bool -> (InputEvent -> IO ()) -> IO ()
readKeyboard continue send = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    while continue $ do
        ifM (hReady stdin) $ do
            a <- getChar
            send (KeyPressed a)

ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m ()
ifM check act = do
    continue <- check
    if continue then act >> return () else return ()

while :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m ()
while continue act = go
    where
        go = ifM continue loop
        loop = act >> go
```

The output thread runs the actions it is sent as long as it is instructed to continue (and once more after it is signaled to stop to make sure all the output happens).

```
runEvents :: IO Bool -> (IO (IO ())) -> IO ()
runEvents continue fetch = (while continue $ fetch >>= id) >> fetch >>= id
```

We can run the example program with `runKeyboard`.

```
main = runKeyboard clockSession_ example
```

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of stuff... Do I really need to build a whole framework in order to achieve the goal?

Comment: I have to say I don't understand how Netwire works. Especially how the wires and events are related together. Are events just special wires? Or are they signals that pass through wires?

Comment: I am kind of stuck on trying to dissect `(fmap ((:[]) . print) <$> periodic 1 . time)`. What is being `fmap`ed on to what? I am intrigued by the infix operator. Is `<$>` trying to apply `(fmap ((:[]) . print))` onto `(periodic 1 . time)`? If so, then why a function of type `f a -> f [IO ()]` can be applied on `Wire s e m a (Event t)`? Is the latter type just the `a` in the function?

Comment: @CarlDong It's normal to make a small framework to hook up an FRP library to the outside world. This is also needed in for other FRP libraries; for example, in reactive-banana you build a framework using [`Reactive.Banana.Frameworks`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.1.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html)

Comment: @CarlDong `Events` in netwire are just an opaque `Maybe` type; An `Event a` is either occurring at this point in time with data `a` or it isn't occurring. They are kept opaque for reasons of correctness. ["This is necessary in order to protect continuous time semantics. You cannot access event values directly."](http://hub.darcs.net/ertes/netwire#events).You can construct an `Event` inside a `Wire` with `now` and `never`. `Event`s expose a `Functor` instance, so you can `fmap` on them. There's nothing special about wires holding events except that you are allowed to use them for switching.

Comment: @CarlDong `periodic 1 . t` has type `(HasTime t s, Monad m) => Wire s e m a (Event t)`. It's a wire of events holding the current time. The events only occur once per second. I want to replace each time `t` with `[print t]`; that's what the function `(:[]) . print` does. Both the `Wire` and the `Event` inside the `Wire` have `Functor` instances. The outer `fmap` (the `<$>`) modifies what's held in the `Wire` replacing `Event t` with `Event [IO ()]`. The inner `fmap` modifies what's held in the `Event`, replacing `t` with `[IO ()]`. `fmap ((:[]) . print) :: Event t -> Event [IO ()]`.

Comment: I am trying to understand the structure, and make this approach single threaded. Type problems are quite difficult, though.

Comment: I have to say that although I solved this specific problem, I still don't know how to use netwire to make any non trivial applications... I may look into reactive-banana too for FRP

Comment: For a (more) non-trivial example, take a look at this [example of a Tetris Attack clone](https://github.com/Mokosha/HsTetrisAttack) I wrote using netwire 5.